# Building a login form with arabic input. How to match records

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, arabic

I am building a form using PHP and I want the user to login with his Arabic name.
I have set the database to UTF-8 and the column to UTF-8.

And I have enter the following code in my PHP script:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

And when I output the result it is written in arabic, so no junk letters ...

Why it doesn't log me in when I use arabic username and when I use english username it logs me in?

Comment: `<form accept-charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: "Login" -- Do you mean via MySQL's login?  Or code you wrote?

Comment: @RickJames I don't think the problem is with character set to UTF-8. Because when I output my text field value I get Arabic characters. But it won't log me in if I use an Arabic username. And it works with english usernames and email address. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: If utf8 is stored in a latin1 column, it will _appear_ to be correct when displayed, while still being stored incorrectly.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table where the user name is stored.

Comment: @RickJames I don't understand. What you mean by `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

1. What is your database encoding? Maybe you input is utf-8, but it has
   been transformed into something else :)

   2. Check your framework (if you are using any) - maybe there is a build in mechanism to transform this
   3. Do you use mysqli to connect? I bet you do - try PDO instead
   4. There is a small discussion here about similar topic: [log in with Arabic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910894/log-in-with-arabic-characters)

Comment: my database encoding is UTF-8. When I out put the username in login script, the arabic characters are shown correct, so there is no problem there. But I can't login with an Arabic username, on the other hand, it works great with English username. What do you think is the problem?